# Como modificar esta consulta en SQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

tengo esta consulta en SQL:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE LOWER(datname) = LOWER(BaseDatos);
```

Pero la estoy ejecutando desde java con jdbc, y necesito pasarle el resultado de la consulta a un ResultSet, pero el problema es que cuando la base de datos no existe el programa me da un NullPointerExcepcion. Mi pregunta es:
Como puedo modificar consulta para que siempre me devuelva algo? Por ejemplo: verdadero si existe la base de datos y falso si no. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Puedes hacer la consulta dentro de un try cath para controlar el NullPointerException y en el catch darle el valor que quieras para cuando no existe la BBDD

Comment: Sigue las recomendaciones de Ramiro Romero pero ten en cuenta que ésta consulta específica accede a tablas propieta de Postgres. Te conviene acceder mejor a las tablas del esquema INFORMATION_SCHEMA que es bastante estandar entre gestores de bases de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que todo el control de la respuesta por parte de la persistencia lo resuelvas en la lógica. Es decir, no te conviene modificar tu consulta SQL.

**¿Por qué no me conviene modificar mi consulta SQL?**. 
No te conviene modificar tu consulta SQL debido a que está redactada de manera general, es decir, con SQL estándar. La ventaja que posees al redactarla de tal manera es que tu capa de persistencia será lo mas cohesiva posible, es decir, podrás cambiar de motor de almacenamiento y tus consultas seguirán funcionando en cada una de ellas. En cambio, si decides utilizar funciones nativas de un determinado motor de base de datos para corroborar el resultado de una consulta, puede que dichas funciones no funcionen en los demás motores, y por ende, tengas que hacer grandes cambios en tu capa de persistencia en caso de cambiar el motor de base de datos.

### **Solución**

Te recomiendo que aprendas a utilizar los bloques TRY/CATCH para capturar las excepciones.
Veamos como quedaría en un ejemplo:

```
public void ejemploPersistencia(){

    //Utilizamos el bloque try/catch mencionado mas arriba
    try{
       //Realizamos la consulta SQL y la capturamos en un objeto de tipo CachedRowSet
       CachedRowSet respuestaSQL = tuConsultaSQL();

       //Recorres tu respuesta
       while(respuestaSQL.next()){
            /*
               Haces todo lo que tengas que hacer.
            */
       }
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
       /*
         Aquí solucionas el problema si quieres
       */
    }

}
```

### **Recomendación**

Intenta no utilizar el objeto ***ResultSet***. ¿Por qué?. Porque el objeto *ResultSet* se debe manipular mientras la conexión se encuentre activa (es decir, abierta), lo cual no es recomendable. Siempre que hayas capturado los valores que necesitas de la persistencia, debes liberar los recursos del motor cerrando la conexión con la base de datos independientemente si ya empezaste a manipular los datos lógicamente. La **solución** para esto es utilizar el objeto ***CachedRowSet***.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías de utilizar try/catch para el control de excepciones. No se como tendrás implementada la conexión con BBDD exactamente, pero aquí te dejo una pequeña plantilla sobre como seria:

```
public ResultSet execSQL() {
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        //Estableces la conexion
        throw new SQLException();
    } catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e) {}
    //Esta parte se ejecutara en caso de que salte una excepción del tipo SQLException o NullPointerException.
    //Te encargas en esta parte de liberar lo que tengas iniciado de la base de datos       

    //En caso de que haya ido bien, estaras devolviendo el ResultSet relleno, si ha ido mal, estaras devolviendo null
    return rs;
}
```

Hay formas mas "correctas" de hacerlo, que quizas te vengan bien si necesitas llevar un mejor control de errores, aunque creo que eso te valdra.